# Similar adjacency matrices of the same graph

Tags: matrices, spectral-graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

I am able to represent a simple graph on $n$ vertices by at most $n!$ different adjacency matrices.
Do all of the adjacency matrices corresponding to the same graph have the same spectrum or are they similar?

Answer (score 3):

Adjacency matrices $A$ and $B$ represent isomorphic graphs if and only if there is a permutation matrix $P$ such that $B=P^TAP$. Since permutation matrices are orthogonal, $P^T=P^{-1}$ and so the matrices $A$ and $B$ are similar.

Comment: In my case,among the $n!$ adjacency matrices representing the same simple graph ,take $A$ and $B$ e.g., how are we sure that we can find a permutation matrix st $B$=$P^T$$A$$P$?

Answer (score 1):

They should have the same spectrum.
I quote from the following book [Machine Learning in Complex Networks, By Thiago Christiano Silva, Liang Zhao]; "While the adjacency matrix depends on the vertex labeling or ordering, its spectrum is graph invariant."